Impostrous, Parity-Preserving Partitions
Four spaceships each have four astronauts—but only three among them are crewmates! Suss out which tag must be the ultimate impostor.
2048-gamecellular-automataconnect-wallcrossword-cluesfour-dimensionalhistoricalnetworknoughts-and-crossesnumber-theoryodd-one-outscrabblesportssudokutic-tac-toevideo-gamesword
Hint:

Both senses of parity are clues:




Some ships hold passengers that maintain a sense of balance.




Impostors are often oddballs who enjoy causing chaos amongst their even-keeled crewmates.




maybe a hint for us

@Lucenaposition hint added :-)

I hope [tag:odd-one-out] is the ultimate impostor :P
